# Catch2 compile error (no such file or directory)

Tags: c++, catch2

I've already used Catch2 for testing sucessfully, but this time a problem occurred. I am pushing Catch2 submodule to me project (this is not a -v2.x branch) and include "*../Catch2/src/catch2/catch_all.hpp*" to my test files. The problem is that in *catch_all.hpp* all of the included .hpp files (like *<catch2/benchmark/catch_benchmark_all.hpp>*, *<catch2/catch_approx.hpp>* and so on) are not found. I've checked paths but they seem to be fine. Any ideas what is wrong with it?
Here's an example of my code.

I am adding a Catch2 submodule with command

*git submodule add https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2.git*

**CMakeFile.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(proj)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set (sources
        ./main.cpp
        ./test_main.cpp
        ./test.cpp)

add_executable(mainApp ${sources})
target_compile_options(mainApp PRIVATE -Wall -pedantic -std=c++17)
target_link_libraries(mainApp)

set (tests
        ./test_main.cpp
        ./test.cpp)

add_subdirectory(Catch2)
add_executable(runTests ${tests})
target_compile_options(mainApp PRIVATE -g)
target_link_libraries(runTests PRIVATE Catch2::Catch2WithMain)
```

**test_main.cpp:**

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#include"Catch2/src/catch2/catch_all.hpp"
```

**test.cpp:**

```
#include"Catch2/src/catch2/catch_all.hpp"

TEST_CASE("BasicTest_1", "FirstTest") {
    REQUIRE(1 == 1);
}
```

**main.cpp** is just a simple helloworld for now.

TEST_CASE doesn't work either, it says "C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations".

Comment: @Scheff'sCat got it. Should I add something to the informtion I've already provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are including `test_main.cpp` and `test.cpp` in `mainApp`.

Which means that files in `mainApp` try to `#include"Catch2/src/catch2/catch_all.hpp"` without linking to the Catch2 library and includes.

Remove the test files from the `mainApp` sources and try again.